# How to test for typename in class?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

In a class template `Foo` I want to check if the template parameter provides a type named `Bar`.

```
struct TypeA {using Bar = int;};
struct TypeB {};
template<class T>Foo{};

void main(){
  Foo<TypeA> a; // I want this to compile
  Foo<TypeB> b; // I want this to not compile, but print a nice message.
}
```

Since I want to combine this with other properties I want a `hasBar` metafunction. So I can combine the boolean values and then use `std::enable_if`.

I tried to understand and use SFINAE but failed:

```
template<class T, class Enable = void>struct hasBar : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct hasBar<T,decltype(std::declval<T::Bar>(),void())> : std::true_type {};
```

`hasBar<TypeA>::value` is always false.

What is the right way to define `hasBar`?

Or is there some better approach then `using` to have a Bar?

Comment: when referring to nested dependent type you need to directly specify the name is type and not e.g. static field... so use `typename` keyword before `T::Bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `typename` before `T::Bar` to specify that it's a nested type name, i.e.

```
template<class T>
struct hasBar<T,decltype(std::declval<typename T::Bar>(),void())> : std::true_type {};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0JCvZswcrCHhRK0q)

BTW: You can use [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) to make it simpler. e.g.

```
template< class, class = std::void_t<> >
struct hasBar : std::false_type { };

template< class T >
struct hasBar<T, std::void_t<typename T::Bar>> : std::true_type { };
```

Comment: yep, I just forgot it again and did not notice. argh

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to use the dependent type as the default value for an unnamed template parameter. Something like this:

```
struct with_bar { using Bar = int; };
struct without_bar { };

template <typename T, typename = typename T::Bar>
struct bar_detector { };

int main() {
  bar_detector<with_bar>();
  bar_detector<without_bar>(); // won' compile
}
```

This yields a pretty usable error message (`g++ 7.3.0`): `error: no type named ‘Bar’ in ‘struct without_bar’`.

Comment: that is true, but I will have to add more checks and most of this are done by typetraits.

Comment: @user9400869 its not perfectly clear from the quesiton if you want a `bool` or just a compiler error, the latter is much simpler to achieve